# python function cannot be called

Tags: python, function, numpy

I have following function typed into a file and saved on to the working folder. However, when I try to call the function by typing `clip = sigclip(0)` It says 'NameError: name 'sigclip' is not defined'. Interestingly if I copy and paste the same codes on the Ipython console followed by the execution of above command would return me the desired output. Anybody has any clue on what's going on?

```
def sigclip(x):
    """returns signal upper and lower limits based on specimen number x"""

    import numpy as np

    clip = np.zeros((2,3,20))

    clip[:,:,0] = [[930,6360,11780],[1275,6660,12060]]
    clip[:,:,1] = [[1090,6550,12000],[1350,6830,12290]]

    out = np.squeeze(clip[:,:,x])
    return out
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on what you have in your question there is no reason why this would happen,  how and where are you running this from?

Comment: Are you importing this function correctly into the script you use where you call the function? Or is it all in the same script?

Comment: I just realized that I have to import the function before execution. I'm a beginner of python and my thinking was functions are callable similar to Matlab. Thanks for the support.

Comment: @duliya, you should read a tutorial, this is pretty basic stuff that you should know http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to do:

```
from my_module import sigclip
```

Where `my_module` is the name of your python file without the .py ending.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does work once I add this line. A followup question for you, is it necessary to import all the functions prior calling them within the script?

Comment: @duliya Some functions are automatically present when you start the interpreter ("built-in functions", see the Python documentation).  Everything else has to be imported. Python is not magic; like other languages the compiler/interpreter has to know where to find all the names.

Comment: To follow on to paul's comment, you also need not import any functions that you have defined in the same module (file basically) or in the case of the interpreter, any functions you've defined in the interpreter (which is why when you copy-pasted your code it worked fine).

Comment: Thanks @PaulCornelius and CrazyCasta. Your comments helps me a lot.